# Cat constantly meowing for food or whenever someone stands

Tags: cats

I am fostering a cat for 1 year now (He’s a street cat with underlying condition and people are more into problem free breeds, so we haven’t been able to find a house for him). He has Hernia and one kidney is infected. He goes to the vet every two months. He is ALWAYS hungry and we have got everything checked and it gets checked every two months , so there’s nothing we know that can cause this.

Whenever someone stands , he meows (Very loudly and relentlessly) to ask for food. I play with him as well. I thought over the months when he gets food on time it will stop but it’s been 1 year now and he’s still constantly at it.

Can someone please guide me how to navigate this?

I am always either playing with him or sitting on the bed is when he doesn’t meow loudly. All the other times I am just scared to do anything else because I get extreme anxiety when he meows like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned your cat is a "street cat." I assume this means that before you he had no one consistently caring for him, and likely experienced food insecurity.  Cats that go through this sometimes end up relentless about food well beyond what you'd normally expect (for obvious reasons).  This would explain why you did the normal thing of just ignoring him (except when it's actually mealtime of course), and even after a year he has not given up.  I think with these cats, it is possible that they may improve eventually, as long as they continue to be in the same home with reliable meals, but it could take a very, very long time, if at all.

My normal advice would be to get him an automatic feeder.  (Even if he eats wet food, there are also wet food models available.)  A cat who has been properly taken care of its whole life would mostly give up on pestering you for food once it figures out it's only getting food from the feeder now, though it might end up spending time staring at the feeder instead.  With a cat that's neurotic about food, I think it might help, but there's also the risk that he would obsessively try to get at the food that is stored in the feeder.  So you might want to try this, but I'd be very careful when introducing the feeder to observe him with it first to determine if you think he's going to try to get into it too much.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have an automatic feeder (I bought it for the same reason as you suggested) but since he is on medication constantly, I never got around to using it. There are no wet food models available in India unfortunately. But I am thinking I will put him on feeder at least 2 times a day and rest is his medication (which I fix with food) time along with meals so I can’t use feeder for that, so I will feed him manually. I thought food insecurity should go away in a year, but you are right, I never thought it could take longer than a year. Thank you for giving that perspective to m

Answer (score 2):

If you respond every time he meows by feeding him, you're training him (or he is training you) that this is approved behavior.

If you know he has had enough food, you don't have time to play with him right now, and he seems to be healthy, let him meow and ignore him.

Or talk back to him. Though that too risks becoming a game and training him to meow when he's  bored.

And sometimes cats seem into yowl just because they like hearing the echoes. Not every meow is meaningful beyond "hey, I'm here. Wanna do something with me?"

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding. I actually only give him food at his food timings. Not because he meows. It’s just that he starts meowing from an hour before the time constantly till it’s time (even though I still give him food only when it’s food time), sometimes even after 1 hour after he had food (in which case I ignore). However, when he relentlessly meows closer to food time, I have to give him food because it’s time (since he is also on medication ). Is there any behavioural training I can do?

Comment: Teaching an animal not to do something is a lot harder than teaching them to do something. I'd suggest checking past answers on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Keshlam's answer, but if after a year that still doesn't work there is maybe something else you could try.

Of course, a cat can't tell whether it's food time, or still one hour early. So, like [Mr. Pavlov](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov), you could introduce another cue for your cat when it's time to eat. Right before feeding time, ring a bell *). Your cat will (hopefully) learn the association: bell = food, no bell = no food

*) Wikipedia tells us Pavlov actually used a metronome. Use whichever you have.

Comment: Very interesting idea and I think this could work. A similar approach can help anxious dogs. The cues (like bells or verbal commands) let the animal know what's about to happen and give it probably a feeling of control (in the sense that they are not just passive objects that things happen to but active agents that are part of the action).

Comment: I really like this bell Idea. I will try this from today. Thank you so much!! Will update here in a month